# Is there a way to allow browserify modules access to the global scope (window object)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, commonjs

**The Scenario**

I'm using Browserify (or NodeJS/CommonJS like imports) to require some JavaScript libraries. However, I'm having trouble getting them to play nice since apparently Browserify by default denies global scope access to all modules. For example, doing this doesn't work;

**file1.js**

```
require('moment');
```

**file2.js**

```
moment(new Date()); // throws moment is undefined
```

But this works by changing the contents of **file1.js** to the following;

```
window.moment = require('moment');
```

---

**The Problem**

This has worked well enough so far, however now I'm having trouble loading the moment timezone library (an extension of MomentJS). Moment Timezone's docs imply both scripts should run on the window global scope by adding them as script tags like so;

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script src="moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

So they can be used like this;

```
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

This however, seems very hard to achieve, since if I try the following;

```
window.moment = require('moment');
require('./../../node_modules/moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020'); // the location of my moment-timezone library
```

I get a runtime error saying that `moment.tz is undefined` (meaning that the second library wasn't run with the global scope). And if I try to add the `window.moment` to the second line of code, I'll be rewriting the first instance of the full library.

**So, in short;**

*Is there a way to allow certain Browserify imports to have global scope access, or to run with the `window` object as their scope?*

I'm aware of the security implications this has, but selectively used, this would be immensely useful while requiring things like JavaScript libraries that need global access to set up themselves correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For libraries like these it's probably much easier to include them externally (meaning with <script> tags) and then make them available to modules processed with browserify with [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim)

Comment: We're already importing heavier libraries with script tags. However, we prefer to bundle the smaller ones into a vendor.min.js file since for high speed internet users, waiting for the server response for a 1-4kb library often takes longer than downloading it.

Comment: That doesn't preclude you from shimming those libraries. So you put tiny libraries into vendor.js, include that on your page with <script>, make them known to browserify with browserify-shim and use them with require('libname') in your modules.

Comment: @weirdan, could you include an example of this?

Comment: I'll try to piece something together and add it as an answer.

BTW, for moment lib specifically it's not really required, since all you need is to install `moment-timezone` with npm and then use it like this: `var moment = require('moment-timezone');` - this will get you an augmented moment module with timezone support and tz data loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put tiny libraries into vendor.js, include that on your page with `<script>`, make them known to `browserify` with `browserify-shim` and use them with `require('libname')` in your modules.

Larger libraries may be included from, say, vendor CDNs, and also be made known to browserify with browserify-shim.

**index.html**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="vendor.js"></script>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Open devtools and inspect the output
    </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cat vendor1.js vendor2.js > dist/vendor.js && cp index.html dist/index.html && browserify index.js -o dist/bundle.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim" : {
    "vendor1" : "global:vendor1",
    "vendor2" : "global:vendor2"
  },
  "browserify" : {
    "transform" : [ "browserify-shim" ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^14.1.0",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.11"
  }
}
```

A couple of things to note about the above `package.json`:

- build: it builds 'application' in dist folder, creating the following structure:

  - dist

    - index.html
    - bundle.js
    - vendor.js
- "browserify" entry: it just adds browserify-shim
- "browserify-shim" entry: it tells browserify that `vendor1` and `vendor2` are available as properties on window (global) object. Browserify won't attempt to bundle them, and `require()` will just return those properties. You need to make sure they are actually available (so `index.html` above includes them with `<script src="vendor.js">`

**index.js**

```js
var momentfromnpm = require('moment-timezone');
var vendor1 = require('vendor1');
var vendor2 = require('vendor2');
console.log("Hello");
console.log("Using module from npm", momentfromnpm().tz("Europe/London").format());
console.log("using a function from vendor1.js (bundled into vendor.js)", vendor1());
console.log("using a 'module' from vendor2.js (bundled to vendor.js)", vendor2.doWork());
```

**vendor1.js**

```js
window.vendor1 = function() { // could also be just `function vendor1()...`
    return "I'm a simple function, defined on a window";
};
```

**vendor2.js**

```js
var vendor2 = { // could also be window.vendor2
    doWork: function() {
        console.log("vendor2 doing work");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the `moment-timezone` package as instructed on the [website](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

```
npm install moment-timezone --save
```

In **file1.js**, define `window.moment` as so:

```
window.moment = require('moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020');
```

This should allow you to use `moment().tz()` in **file2.js**